# Php uses other class than specified

Tags: php, laravel

I am experiencing a very weird issue.

I have two classes, one is in *App\Projects\github\Units\github_login* and the other is *App\Projects\github\Schema\github_login*

The Schema file is just a scheme which shows the *skeletal structure* of the file *App\Projects\github\Units\github_login*.

In fact, it should never ever get loaded and executed, it is just for humans.

However, PHP always executes this file instead of **App\Projects\github\Units\github_login**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Selenium;
use App\Models\Project;
use App\Projects\github\Units\github_login;

class PlayController extends BasePlayController
{
    private $github_login;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->github_login = new github_login();
    }

    /**
    * Play a testcase X times.
    *
    * @param string $Project
    * @param string $Unit
    * @param string $Scenario
    * @param string $Testcase
    * @param int $Times
    * @param int $Delay
    * @return /Illuminate/View/View
    */
    public function PlayCase($Project, $Unit, $Scenario, $Testcase, $Times=1, $Delay=3)
    {
        $SeleniumObj = $this->Selenium;

        $Unit =  $Project .'_'. $Unit;

        switch ($Project) {
            case 'github':
                switch ($Unit) {
                    case 'github_login':
                        switch ($Scenario) {
                            case 'standard':
                                 $this->callCase(array($this->github_login, 'standard'), $Testcase, $Times, $Delay);
                                break;
                            default:
                                $SeleniumObj->logMessage[$SeleniumObj->index]['TestcaseTitle'] = $Scenario;
                                $SeleniumObj->setMessage(2,"Das Szenario '<strong>". $Scenario ."</strong>' existiert nicht!", '');
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                $SeleniumObj->setTitle('Projekt existiert nicht.');
                $SeleniumObj->setMessage(2,'Das Projekt <strong>'. $Project .'</strong> existiert nicht. (Fix: einfach neuen Testfall anlegen)', '');
        }

        return view('show.report')->with('driver',        $SeleniumObj->driver)
                                  ->with('ScenarioName',  $Scenario)
                                  ->with('logMessage',    $SeleniumObj->logMessage)
                                  ->with('execScriptRet', $SeleniumObj->execScriptRet)
                                  ->with('screenshot',    $SeleniumObj->screenshot)
                                  ->with('PlayAll',       false);
    }
```

As you can see in the screenshot, it even loads the right one, but how on earth does it execute the one in folder `Schema`?

[image]

I am making selenium tests btw and use the github login page for start.

### UPDATE:

**BasePlayController - callCase:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Selenium;

class BasePlayController
{
    public $Selenium;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->Selenium = new Selenium();
    }

    public function callCase($thisFunction, $Testcase, $Times=1, $Delay=1)
    {
        $SeleniumObj = $this->Selenium;

        if (is_numeric($Times)) {
            for($i = 1; $i <= $Times; $i++) {

                $thisFunction($SeleniumObj, $Testcase);
                sleep($Delay);
            }
        } else {
            $SeleniumObj->logMessage[$SeleniumObj->index]['TestcaseTitle'] = 'Falscher Parameter für Times.';
            $SeleniumObj->setErrorMessage("Times muss eine Zahl sein! (Gegeben: '<strong>". $Times ."</strong>')", '');
        }
    }

 ...
```

### UPDATE 2

Autloader Entry in *vendor\composer\autoload_classmap.php*

```
'App\\Projects\\github\\Units\\github_login' => $baseDir . '/app/Projects/github/Schema/github_login.php',
```

I tried to change it to

```
'App\\Projects\\github\\Units\\github_login' => $baseDir . '/app/Projects/github/Units/github_login.php',
```

but it made no difference.

Comment: Only the default laravel autoloader.

Comment: It is __unclear__, how do you understand that another file is included.

Comment: Because a syntax error is thrown and It only works if I fix it in the file *App\Projects\github\Schema\github_login*. Even though the error is in both files.

Comment: What does BasePlayController do? Does it use this file?

Comment: Maybe `Units\github_login` uses `Schema\github_login` ?

Comment: @kerbholz, i don't think so, this is the first line in *App\Projects\github\Units\github_login.php*: `namespace App\Projects\github\Units;`

Comment: Move/rename that file and see if your code still works. If it doesn't your assumption "_In fact, it should never ever get loaded and executed, it is just for humans._" might have been wrong.

Comment: Code does not worked without that file, I already checked it before by clearing the whole code in the file.

Comment: what is the namespace line in Schema\github_login ?

Comment: @lagbox, it is the same but it should not mather since I never include or use this file. The autoloader messed something up for whatever reason after I installed a new project with composer.

Comment: it has nothing to do with you including it, composer scanned and found it and classmapped it, and classmapping doesn't care about directory structure

Comment: @lagbox, then why was Unit mapped to Schema?

Comment: because the `github_login` class in Schema has that namespace ... if your reply "it is the same" means that both those files have the same namespace declaration

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 files declaring the same class. Composer is scanning a directory finding classes and classmapping them to their location. It just happens to be since there can only be one by key that its pointing the the duplicate class in `Schema`. Would be my quick thoughts without digging into the internals.

The file says it is in X namespace and the classname is Y ... that is what it is regardless of where it physically exists.

I guess you can not have 2 files declaring the same class like that (anywhere in a folder that gets classmapped), or make the duplicate not a valid php file for use, maybe making it `.phps`.
... and redump the autoload.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. I had to change the autoloader entry in `vendor\composer\autoload_static.php` from

```
'App\\Projects\\github\\Units\\github_login' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/app/Projects/github/Schema/github_login.php',
```

to

```
'App\\Projects\\github\\Units\\github_login' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/app/Projects/github/Units/github_login.php',
```

But I wonder why I have to do this manually.